# Linq2SQL strange behavior

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

This code is created in LinqPad. The result is, without explicit casting, it create a new test list when calling the constructor. Why? My thought is how the compiler treats enclosure variable when optimising the code involves slow query or static list and enuerator is involved.

**Edit:** I get a new List in each Test object created in the linq query, so the hashcode dump looks like and they all referenece to different lists.

58450264
41170820
58857649
541983

```
void Main()
{
    List<Test> test= new List<Test>();
    //with static list, it works correctly
    //  test.AddRange(new []{"A", "B", "C"}.Select(u=> new Test(u,test)).ToList());
    //  test.Count.Dump();
    //  test[0]._test.Count().Dump();
    //  test[1]._test.Count().Dump();

    //This works incorrectly
    this.Users.Select(u=> new Test(u.Name,test)).ForEach(t => test.Add(t));
    //This works corrrectly
    //this.Users.Select(u=> new Test(u.Name,(IList<Test>)test)).ForEach(t => test.Add(t));
    test.Count.Dump();
    test[0]._test.Count().Dump();
    test[1]._test.Count().Dump();
    test[2]._test.Count().Dump();

    test.GetHashCode().Dump();
    test[0]._test.GetHashCode().Dump();
    test[1]._test.GetHashCode().Dump();
    test[2]._test.GetHashCode().Dump();
}

public class Test
{
    public IList<Test> _test;
    public Test(string name, IList<Test> test)
    {
        _test = test;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it because 'test' is declared as `List<Test>` ??? You are passing a List<Test> object to constructor accepting IList<Test>. There's nothing strange to me here. They are compatible types, so no explicit casting required.

Comment: @Alex buty List<T> implements IList<T>, why do I need explicit conversion? Also the static list example works fine

Comment: you don't need explicit conversion, I thought this was your question? If you pass a List<Type> to IList<Type>, this is normal behaviour in C#. The IList<Type> needs concrete implementation.

Comment: ok I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: if you cast List to IList before passing to the constructor, then it behaves correctly?

Comment: @Alex, yes, correct. it gives the same list